# .htaccess rewriterule asterisk quantifier not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule in my .htaccess to parse a URL like this:

```
https://www.myweb.com/folder/ABCD/HIJK/wxyz/?dclid=Tzf3YrswCFZNmGwodtrALQg
```

into this:

```
https://anotherweb.com/folder/?param1=ABCD&param2=HIJK&param3=wxyz&dclid=Tzf3YrswCFZNmGwodtrALQg
```

"ABCD" could be any string **or empty**. 
"1234" could be any string. 
"wxyz" could be any string.

So, this could also happens if first param is empty:

```
https://www.myweb.com/folder//HIJK/wxyz/?dclid=Tzf3YrswCFZNmGwodtrALQg
```

This is the rewriterule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ https://anotherweb.com/folder/?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L,QSA]
```

And everything is working fine in all cases where first param ("ABCD" in previous example) is not empty.

But when that param is not empty and we receive `...folder//HIJK/...` it is not able to parse param1 as empty and I get a 404 http code.

I thought that this part `([^/]*)` of the regex would do the trick but it seems that I'm missing something here.

Anybody can help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/.]*)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/ https://anotherweb.com/folder/?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Please check if the above code is working as expected.